# Remote Desktop Software with low latency

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, vnc, latency

I am searching for a remote desktop software (Linux/Windows/Mac) which has a very low latency between input+output (lower then 1 sec). Some VNC (UltraVNC, RealVNC) solutions have a latency of 1-2 seconds - even if connected directly over a switch. 
Anyone experience with that? What would be the best software solution?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: FWIW, I have never had a 1+ second latency using VNC between nodes on a local network segment.

Comment: Try having two monitors, VNC crawls even on a fast system if you have something like 6000 horizontal pixels on your screens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been extremely happy with [NoMachine (NX](http://www.nomachine.com)) for Linux (Mac, Windows and Linux clients) and [Ericom Blaze](http://www.ericom.com/ericom_blaze.asp) for accelerated RDP to Windows. These have been my choices for remote display of monitoring and financial trading applications. But yes, the other comments about your local network do apply. VNC should work well on a local network.

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer I was looking for! Any other advices? (I also want to use RDP for financial trading and the latency just sucks)

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't in your choice of VNC software, it's somewhere else -- I've never seen VNC with a latency like that over a local network.  I'm at a loss to even make suggestions as to what to check, apart from really general things like "does your LAN suck?".

Comment: I had to realyse, that I was connected over VPN to another location and then back to the switch my VNC-test-PC was connected to. So thanks for the hint, VNC over local network works great. But I am mainly looking for software for remote servers - and there I tried some, but again latency was very big. (And yes, the Server has a 100mbit/s and I have a 10mbit/s connection)